# What is the source of this blog post about maximum credit scores?

Tags: credit-score, fico-score

So I'm reading up on credit scoring, and I came across [this posting](http://www.mint.com/blog/credit-2/can-i-score-that-elusive-fico-850/):

> The maximum score held by a U.S consumer is…834.  There are consumers in New York, Florida, New Jersey and Pennsylvania who have achieved that score.

....

> The lowest score held by a U.S consumer is…387.  That honor goes to a consumer living in the state of Virginia.  That 387 is by far the lowest of the low.  The second lowest is 404 (out of New York).  There are also some 407s in Ohio and Texas.

How does one even get access to figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting article, thanks for the link.

He used to work at Fair Isaac Corporation (FICO) and also at Equifax. I assume that he saw those scores in the course of his work there, or that he used a contact there to get the information.

Source: http://www.johnulzheimer.com/about/

Comment: I am sure there are aggregate reports in the industry that report on errata like this.  Being as it is devoid of personal data and likely the closest they get being by state there would be little privacy concerns.  Since he is an industry expert he would have access to some of these reports.